# changing $routeProvider to $urlRouterProvider

Tags: angularjs, controller

I am new to angularjs and trying to change my codes using $routeProvider to $urlRouterProvider.

Here is my code for using $routeProvider:

```
.when('/cars', {
    templateUrl: 'views/cars.html',
    controller: 'CarsCtrl'
  })
.when('/cars/:id', {
    templateUrl: 'views/cardetail.html',
    controller: 'CarDetailCtrl'
  })
```

and my html looks like this:

```
<div class="list-group"  ng-repeat="car in cars">
  <a href="#/cars/{{car.id}}" class="list-group-item active">
   <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{car.id}}</h4>
   <p class="list-group-item-text">Car name: {{car.name}}</p>
   <p class="list-group-item-text">Car date: {{car.date}}</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

So when I click on one of the car arrays, it leads to cardetail.html.
This code works in using $routeProvider. Now, I am trying to convert this to using $urlRouterProvider, and I am having a bit of problem.

What I did so far looks like this (which doesn't work):

```
.state('cars', {
    url: '/cars',
    parent: 'dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'views/modules/cars/cars.html?v='+window.app_version,
    controller: 'CarsCtrl'
})
.state('carDetail', {
    url: '/car/:id',
    parent: 'dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'views/modules/cars/carsDetail.html?v='+window.app_version,
    controller: 'CarDetailCtrl'
})
```

and my HTML:

```
<pageheader pagename="Cars" subtitle="your cars"></pageheader>

<div class="list-group"  ng-repeat="car in cars">
 <a ng-href="#/carDetail/{{id}}" class="list-group-item active">
  <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{car.id}}</h4>
  <p class="list-group-item-text">Car name: {{car.name}}</p>
  <p class="list-group-item-text">Car date: {{car.date}}</p>
 </a>
</div>
```

Is there a problem in my HTML?
help much appreciated.

Comment: Use `$stateProvider`, not `$urlRouterProvider`.

Comment: i'm using $stateProvider already

Answer (score 0):

Use `ui-sref` to build your links.

```
<a ui-sref="carDetail({id: id})" class="list-group-item active">
```